# Developing Browser Based Database Application?

Tags: web-applications, cross-browser

I need to develop a series of browser based reports / data inquiries where user can input search criteria and the result will be returned from a database. and the output is expected to be presented with a modern look and feel and It is expected to be used on mobile device.

I am totally new in developing browser based application. The closest I came to was building a drupal 6 site on ubuntu and using jquery to spice it up.

Could you please suggest what I should use for the development?
The database is MSSQL-2000, but I am willing to move the necessary data to a new database if I have to.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's a rather vague question. Maybe you should learn more about your programming language of choice until you feel comfortable in it and/or tackle problems as you encounter them along the way?

Comment: Do you have a server? They only way to handle this without some kind of server-side scripting would be a couchapp.

Comment: @deceze: Yes, I understand the question is vague, but I was hoping for a direction (combination of platform, language, framework...) which could save me time coz there are so many choices out there.

Comment: @Raynos: I have a ubuntu 11.04 which I can use for the project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so here is my subjective example:

I am using Debian Linux as a server OS, with PHP 5.3 as serverside scripting and MySQL 5.1 as database.

I choose PHP because it's easy to work with, easy to learn, and has already installed extensions for MySQL. so i can just use mysql related functions to access the database.

On the client side i use jQuery for interactivity with different plugins for fancy stuff. The layout developed by a professional desiner who hadns me the HTMLs and CSS so i only need to add the text i get from the database and put some javascript (jQuery) to make ajax requests to the server.

As a SDK i use Zend Studio but a free alternative with the same editing features is Eclipse PDT.

I think this is the most simple, easy to setup architecture for simple web based applications that need to send requests to server and display results into HTML.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dan! Just what I needed. I have lots of digging to do now!

Answer (score 1):

This question could have a large number of responses, most of them contradictory.

Web based applications, need a browser to render the results and a server to process.

There are many languages that allow you to develop web based application : PHP (very wide usage), C# and ASP.NET , Java Servlets, Ruby on Rails, even Cgi scripts in Python, Perl or whatever.

You should use the language that's most appropriate for your needs.

Than you should need a framework to ease your development.

For PHP you can choose between popular ones like : Simphony, Zend Framework, Code Ignitor, Yii
I don't know of good frameworks for other technologies but if you decide on something, you can ask a more clear question, or search the net.

The last point is the browser interface, that is javascript. There are some frameworks here like jQuery that you used. Others are : Yahoo User Interfaces, a more robust one, Dojo, and others as well...

Comment: The perl community will hate your for associating them with cgi scripts. That's legacy technology, there are significantly better options these days

Comment: :) lol. I guess so, but... i still see this kind of apps so, i just included it here. As i said, any answer to this question will rise discussions...

Comment: Since I am not proficient with any of the above technologies... I was really hoping for someone begin really subjective and tells me The Preferred Technology for this kind of apps is e.g. ROR + JQUERY + LINUX + MYSQL... and I would start from those... Ha ha.. I guess it isn't happening... Thanks a lot :)